# find rows in table where all column values are within a specific range

Tags: r

I have a table with an id column (row names: x1-x5)followed by 20 columns with numerical values. I need to find rows where all column values are within a given range e.g. 1000-2000.

```
x1  614.514 587.3   719.25  604.801 669.595 1703.74 1744.23 1876.09 846.224 2314.82 1348.99 2013.43 1867.24 1762.6  1566.74 1590.8  1587.01 1544.88 1617.78 1309.69

x2  3254.02 5258.79 2648.52 2644.17 3222.8  4127.27 5254.42 5434.76 6102.35 5890.25 5619.38 3346.84 3696.11 4581.44 1468.48 4628.4  4969.09 4623.34 4842.4  5542.33

x3  596.369 561.562 860.907 612.952 636.416 1246.69 1122.82 1125.08 508.835 1173.63 1046.1  1078.4  1238.64 1042.9  950.404 1120.76 998.17  1075.62 1115.9  914.933

x4  1343.95 1712.76 952.298 1018.87 1084.32 578.646 707.197 599.226 1337.18 1686.72 840.897 539.199 533.319 563.101 736.027 661.588 711.23  657.246 687.865 793.797

x5  1118.95 1325.52 1287.7  1666.06 1740.34 1799.18 1956.39 1483.32 2998    4045.77 2176.8  1693.72 1896.93 2041.38 1014.72 2128.76 2043.94 1831.81 1936.41 2275.93
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `rowSums`

```
df[rowSums(df >= 1000 & df <= 2000) == ncol(df), ]
```

Using `apply`

```
df[apply(df >= 1000 & df <= 2000, 1, all), ]
```

Using `filter_all` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. >= 1000 & . <= 2000))
```